# duplicate row in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create duplicate table view cell above the last tap cell which consist the data of last tap cell. But this is happening only bottom to top view.if i change the order it is return wrong value. This is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *lastTapCell;
     lastTapCell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _txtDetailStr = lastTapCell.textLabel.text;
    _lastTapCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row  inSection:indexPath.section];

}

- (void)createDuplicateText:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)press {

    if (press.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        [_stringArray addObject:_txtDetailStr];
        [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[_lastTapCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the hierarchy of viewcontroller in my storyboard.**

[image]
**This is my structure of viewcontroller swift file.**

```
class LocationVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblLocation: UITableView!

var selectedCells:[IndexPath] = []
var selectedCell: IndexPath?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func selectCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedCell = indexPath
    self.tblLocation.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : LocationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LocationCell") as! LocationCell
    cell.lblCell.text = String(indexPath.row)
    if selectedCells.count > 0 {
        if indexPath.row == selectedCell!.row - 1 {
            cell.lblCell.text = String(selectedCell!.row)
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedCells.append(indexPath)
    self.selectCell(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

}

**This is my structure of tableviewCell file.**

```
class LocationCell : UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var lblCell: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` is returning a fixed value.  You should be adding to the data that feeds the table rather than manually adding cells to the table yourself.  The table should manage the cells itself, you shouldn't have to add any cells yourself.